# Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100) quits unexpectedly on update to latest package versions

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

Xcode quits unexpectedly when I try to reset, resolve or update the latest package versions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1.check your Mac current os version(update if needed).

otherwise

1.Try restarting your computer.
2.uninstall Xcode again download Xcode directly in the App Store.